# PC unresponsive after clamscan

Tags: clamav

I ran `clamscan -r -i` without specifying the drive, because I have multiple and wanted it to check all of them. My entire PC is now unresponsive. What do I do?

- Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, 64-bit
- AMD Fx-8320 eight-core processort x 8
- NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
- 23.5 GiB RAM, 580.1 GB HDD (500 GB main partition, 401 GB free)

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: I powered it off manually, booted up, and ran `sudo clamscan -r -i /` and I don't see any process in System Monitor, but my CPU is very active. There are usually two active cores, and they mirror each other. Why?